# R - Copy values within a group

Tags: r, copy, replicate

I have a dataframe where I have the total number of points someone scored in the past 3 years (2016, 2017, 2018), but also columns with their number of points per year.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
myDF <- data.frame(ID =c(1,1,1,2,2,3,4),
 Dates= c("2016", "2017", "2018", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2016"),
 Total_Points = c(5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 2, 3),
 Points2016 = c(3, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, 3),
 Points2017 = c(NA,1,NA,NA,2,NA,NA),
 Points2018= c(NA,NA,1, NA, NA, 2, NA))
```

The problem is that I would like to copy the values of columns "Points2016", "Points2017" and "Points2017" for every group so that their entries look the same.

I'm not sure the explanation was clear so this would be my expected output:

```
myDF_final <- data.frame(ID =c(1,1,1,2,2,3,4),
               Dates= c("2016", "2017", "2018", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2016"),
               Total_Points = c(5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 2, 3),
               Points2016 = c(3, 3, 3, 2, 2, NA, 3),
               Points2017 = c(1,1,1,2,2,NA,NA),
               Points2018= c(1,1,1, NA, NA, 2, NA))
```

Basically, I would like to have the same values for the columns "Points201X" for every ID.

Answer (score 14):

I think you could just fill by the `ID` group in both directions. With `dplyr` and `tidyr` we could do:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

myDF %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  fill(Points2016, Points2017, Points2018) %>% 
  fill(Points2016, Points2017, Points2018, .direction = "up")
```

Returns:

> ```
>   ID Dates Total_Points Points2016 Points2017 Points2018
> 1  1  2016            5          3          1          1
> 2  1  2017            5          3          1          1
> 3  1  2018            5          3          1          1
> 4  2  2016            4          2          2         NA
> 5  2  2017            4          2          2         NA
> 6  3  2018            2         NA         NA          2
> 7  4  2016            3          3         NA         NA
> ```

Also, if you have a bunch of years say 1970 - 2018, you could do something like:

```
myDF %>% 
  gather(points_year, points, -c(ID, Dates, Total_Points)) %>% 
  group_by(ID, points_year) %>% 
  fill(points) %>% 
  fill(points, .direction = "up") %>% 
  spread(points_year, points)
```

So as to avoid typing out every year. However, this involves gathering and spreading the data which might be unnecessary assuming the variables we need to `fill` follow a consistent naming convention. In this case, there is a consistent naming convention and we could use the [`tidyselect`](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyselect) backend of `dplyr` to fill all variables that start with the word "Points":

```
myDF %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  fill(starts_with("Points"), .direction = "down") %>% 
  fill(starts_with("Points"), .direction = "up")
```

---

Alternatively, this seems to work with `data.table` and `zoo`:

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)

dt <- as.data.table(myDF)

dt <- dt[, names(dt)[4:6] := lapply(.SD, function(x) na.locf0(x)), by = ID, .SDcols = 4:6]
dt <- dt[, names(dt)[4:6] := lapply(.SD, function(x) na.locf0(x, fromLast = TRUE)), by = ID, .SDcols = 4:6]
```

This one liner seems to do it all in one go as well:

```
dt[, names(dt)[4:6] := lapply(.SD, function(x) na.locf(x)), by = ID, .SDcols = 4:6]
```

> ```
>    ID Dates Total_Points Points2016 Points2017 Points2018
> 1:  1  2016            5          3          1          1
> 2:  1  2017            5          3          1          1
> 3:  1  2018            5          3          1          1
> 4:  2  2016            4          2          2         NA
> 5:  2  2017            4          2          2         NA
> 6:  3  2018            2         NA         NA          2
> 7:  4  2016            3          3         NA         NA
> ```

Comment: What is "gather" doing? What are the columns "points_year" and "points"? Thanks a lot

Comment: `gather` is taking a wide dataset and making it long by collapsing it into key-value pairs. `points_year` is the name I'm assigning to the key variable and `points` is the name I'm assigning to the value variable. See tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/gather.html

Comment: Thanks! I will try that tonight, my dataset is quite big and it says that it will take 4h to compute :)

Comment: Happy to help. You might want to try the `data.table` solution, should be faster. I’m not a `data.table` wizard though :)

Comment: I find it strange that there is not a more "elegant" solution to this in `dplyr` like `.direction = "any"`.

Comment: I'm not sure how "any" would work. It would still have to pick its initial direction and specifying makes it explicit.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `zoo::na.locf0` to fill `NA`s from the top & bottom.

```
library(tidyverse);
library(zoo);
myDF %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate_at(vars(contains("Points20")), funs(na.locf0(., fromLast = F))) %>%
    mutate_at(vars(contains("Points20")), funs(na.locf0(., fromLast = T)))
## A tibble: 7 x 6
## Groups:   ID [4]
#     ID Dates Total_Points Points2016 Points2017 Points2018
#  <dbl> <fct>        <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
#1    1. 2016            5.         3.         1.         1.
#2    1. 2017            5.         3.         1.         1.
#3    1. 2018            5.         3.         1.         1.
#4    2. 2016            4.         2.         2.        NA
#5    2. 2017            4.         2.         2.        NA
#6    3. 2018            2.        NA         NA          2.
#7    4. 2016            3.         3.        NA         NA
```